# Implementing MD5: Inconsistent endianness?

Tags: hash, byte, md5, bit

So I tried implementing the MD5 algorithm according to [RFC1321](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt) in C# and it works, but there is one thing about the way the padding is performed that I don't understand, here's an example:

If I want to hash the string "1" (without the quotation marks) this results in the following bit representation: **10001100**

The next step is appending a single "1"-Bit, represented by **00000001** (big endian), which is followed by "0"-Bits, followed by a 64-bit representation of the length of the original message (low-order word first).

Since the length of the original message is 8 (Bits) I expected 0000000000000000000000000000**1**000 00000000000000000000000000000000 to be appended (low-order word first). However this does not result in the correct hash value, but appending 000**1**0000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 does.

This looks as if suddenly the little-endian format is being used, but that does not really seem to make any sense at all, so I guess there must be something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, for md5 you have to add message length in little-endian.

So, message representation for "1" -> 49 -> **00110001**, followed by single bit and zeroes. And after add message length in reversed order of bytes (the least significant byte first).

You could also check permutations step by step on this site: https://cse.unl.edu/~ssamal/crypto/genhash.php.

Or there: https://github.com/MrBlackk/md5_sha256-512_debugger

[image: md5_debug_mode]